# Is there an easy trick for making FlipView show a little bit of the items on the left and right of the current item?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

The FlipView control is great, but sometimes it's hard to show the user that there are more items.

Is there anything I can do to "correctly" make the FV show a little of the objects to the left and right of the currently displaying item (if they exist of course)?

I looked at the templates and could not find anything. Also thought of the following things, but decided against them:

- Use a horizontal listview: Making the listview snap seems like it's pretty darn hard and hacky.
- Manually add the prev/next item to the left and right. Hacky and does not animate when the FV animates.

Any other ideas?

(Win8)

Answer (score 1):

Flipview might not be ideal for what you want to achieve. You could use three image placeholders. One to the left partially in view. One main and center. One to the right partially in view. When the user swipes across the central image, find the image in the right/left and replace the image in the center moving the index across your collection of images. You could also add maybe two buttons over/next to the image placeholder. Does that help?

Comment: Not really. FlipView is nice because it animates the contained element etc. This is essentially re-implementing it (it may be a solution, but I am looking to leverage the FlipView, which may very well be impossible)